# magento siderbar option order

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

how can i changed order of items in side bar

**current case**
1: as of now it shows filter in below order
 shop by , price and then other filter

what to do if u want below order

price, shop by , then other filter

i think there must be some setting or way to do it via admin ,

please tell me way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin panel Catalog > Attibutes > Manage Attributes > Edit any attribute > Frontend Properties > Position. Here you can add the order position for attribute filter.